# boto3 module throwing Attribute error while accessing its attribute

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, python-packaging

I have installed a python package `boto3` version 1.7.19 using the below command:
`/home/hdpadmin/anaconda3/bin/pip install boto3`
The package is getting successfully installed but when I try to access its `client()` or `resource()` attribute it is throwing below error:

```py
import boto3
client=boto3.client()
```

`AttributeError: module 'boto3' has no attribute 'client`